# Почему при запуске кода выдается ошибка('NoneType' object has no attribute 'text')?

Tags: python, парсер, lxml

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'
}
def g(url):
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    ip = soup.find('div', class_='ip').text
    print(ip)


def main():
    g(url='https://2ip.ru')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Потому что метод не нашел в 'DOM' html тег 'div' с классом ip

Comment: Получить IP проще с других сервисов, которые выдают ответ без всяких тегов, текстом в чистом виде. Например: http://v4.ipv6-test.com/api/myip.php (Либо IPv6: http://v6.ipv6-test.com/api/myip.php)

Answer (score 0):

Что бы получить по данному методу нужный тег и его данные нужен JavaScript который в библиотеке requests (как я понял вы используете его для доступа к html) не реализован и ответ в этом случае вы получаете несколько иной, чем видите в браузере. Вы можете удостовериться в этом, если просто сделаете print() для html документа, который вы получили.

Для доступа к тегу по вашему методу можно использовать selenium или playwright которые полностью эмулируют работу браузера, то есть загружают страничку так же, как видите вы в браузере.

Но, кстати, получить ip можно даже и с этого ответа, который дает requests, а именно с помощью данного метода:

```
div_gen = soup.find('div').stripped_strings
str_1, str_2, str_3, str_4, ip = div_gen
print(ip)
```

На будущее просто посмотрите и изучите DOM html документа который приходит вам в ответ, часто он может отличаться от того что вы видите в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, по правилам хорошего стиля программирования, функцию *g()* надо было написать вот так:

```
def g(url):
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Страница {url} не найдена")
        return
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    ip = soup.find('div', class_='ip')
    # Если find() не может ничего найти, он возвращает None:
    if ip is None:
        print("Ничего не найдено")
        return
    else:
        print(ip.text)
```

И тогда бы вы увидели, в чём причина проблемы:

```
Ничего не найдено
```

А вот почему этот тег  не находится, вопрос другой..

Comment: Там 503 код возвращает, поэтому был бы первый принт

Comment: @ArtemFilippov - "Там 503 код возвращает" - На самом деле, ситуация несколько сложнее. Я запускал эту программу несколько раз. В начале код был 200 и просто не находился нужный тег. Я смотрел HTML код, полученный из get(url). Там,  в самом деле, было нечто совсем другое. 

Но, где-то с третьей попытки начал возвращаться код 503. Если это - учебная задача, то она не самая простая. Для начала надо бы использовать proxy и *fake_useragent*.  А уж после этого - разбираться с тем, что выдаётся на самом деле.

Comment: Вот хорошая статья, как победить 503 код: https://pknerd.medium.com/5-strategies-to-write-unblock-able-web-scrapers-in-python-5e40c147bdaf

Comment: статья хорошая, много полезного на самом деле
но буду признателен, если вы скинете скриншот (можно в лс) что вам запрос с библиотекой requests на этот сайт хоть один раз вернул код 200

Comment: @ArtemFilippov - "скинете скриншот". Намёк понял :-) Попытался повторить код 200 - не получилось. "Замаскировал" как рекомендовано в статье, получил какую-то загадочную ошибку прокси:

requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='2ip.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:992)'))))

Comment: Что делать с этим, я уже не знаю. В моём списке прокси была строка для HTTPS, так что я не понял сообщения. По любому, как я уже говорил, это задачка - не для начинающих! Могу прислать исход этой прогроаммки, только замажу параметры прокси. Если у Вас есть свои - подставьте и попробуйте.